# How to print in a file the time it took a command to run?

Tags: shell, testing, time

I would like to print in a file the result of a `time`.

For example `time ls -lRa /` print the time at the end of the execution. And I would like to print it in a file like `toto.txt`

I tried `time ls -lRa / >> toto.txt`, but as I thought it printed in also the result of ls..

Is there any way I can do to print only the time and let the print of ls in the standard output ?

(The aim is to make a script which will print in a file something like :

```
testing ls -lRa / ...
real    1m14.999s
user    0m43.928s
sys     0m3.681s
```

)

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with the posted answer by Pablo Antonio as it redirects any error output from the `ls -lRa` to the file `toto.txt`. Try this:

```
time (ls -lRa / > /dev/null 2>&1) > toto.txt 2>&1
```

You could also write a script, create a file `timePrint.sh`, add the below and run `chmod u+x timePrint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "testing $* ..." > toto.txt
time ($* > /dev/null 2>&1) > toto.txt 2>&1
```

Then use it like `./timePrint.sh ls -lRa /`

Comment: Yes, that's just what I saw after, I'm going to try your solution !

Comment: You should have replaced `a` with `toto.txt` in my answer, which I've edited to reflect that now

Comment: It's good now, but I got one more problem, why is the execution time different when I try `time (LD_PRELOAD=./libmy_malloc.so ls -lRa / > /dev/null 2>&1) >> time.log 2>&1` in a term and with the script ?

Like, with the script it takes me 1 or 2 secs and in a term more than 30 secs..

Comment: Which one did you run first, the script or in the terminal?

Comment: The script, it always takes less than 30 secs, in a term if i try `ls -lRa /` time gives me more than a minute. I would like to have a script which will tell me the time it takes always, without any "saving" to improve the time is you see what I mean..

Comment: OK I see what you mean. The reason it is slower when you run it in the term is because printing such a huge amount of output requires a lot of I/O communication which is inherently slow. Printing to the screen takes a lot of time. But when you hide the output, the computer does not need to print to screen so it is much faster.

Comment: Yes, I copy/pasted it : `time (LD_PRELOAD=./libmy_malloc.so ls -lRa / > /dev/null 2>&1) >> time.log 2>&1` and got `real    0m2.483s
user    0m1.109s
sys     0m1.374s` with the script and
`real    0m44.539s
user    0m42.984s
sys     0m1.560s`
in the terminal...

Comment: Oh so in both cases you do not see the output?

Comment: As I'm redirecting it to /dev/null, i'm not printing anything on the screen, nor with the script nor with in the terminal. I use the same command, in the both it doesn't print anything but time is always different.

Comment: I tried running `time (LD_PRELOAD=./libmy_malloc.so ls -lRa / > /dev/null 2>&1) > time.log 2>&1` in a script and in a term and I got the same time for both. It may be because the results are already stored in the cache when you ran it in the script so it was faster.

Comment: Running it from a script should not make a difference to the time, there are probably other lower level mechanisms causing this effect

Comment: OKAY ! I know what as the problem, coming from me, I'm really sorry I didn't saw it earlier.. The path to my lib was wrong in the test in my terminal as it's not in `./` but in `../` ! It's working perfectly now, thanks a lot ! Really sorry to have taken your time for nothing..

Comment: Anyway, @texasflood is right about the cache. You can see very different times for the same command because of that; specially in such I/O-intensive commands. So keep that in mind too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Assuming you're using bash, you can do: `{ time ls -lRa /; } 2> toto.txt`.

You can also get rid of `ls`'s output (standard output and standard error) using something like:

```
{ time ls -lRa / > /dev/null 2>&1; } 2> toto.txt
```

Comment: Just one question, is it possible to avoid the errors of ls in the file ? Like : "ls: cannot open directory /home/lost+found: Permission denied" ?

Comment: Of course. The redirection operator without any number means "redirect standard output". You can tell bash to "redirect standard error to standard output, and then redirect all that to `/dev/null`" with `> /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Okay, but now I got one more problem as under your post.. The execution time is really different of the real time execution in my terminal. Is there any way to avoid this ?